# Symfony 3: XLIFF with same source and target?

Tags: symfony, translation, xliff

I am trying to get in to Translating using Symfony 3. I have read all of the documentation but am getting hung up on how to handle the default language. For example this I know this is the XLIFF file I would use for French

```
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<file source-language="en" target-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="symfony_is_great">
            <source>Symfony is great</source>
            <target>J'aime Symfony</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
</file>
```

but what do I do for English? Do I just duplicate the message in the source and the target like this?

```
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" target-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="symfony_is_great">
                <source>Symfony is great</source>
                <target>Symfony is great</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

It just seems weird to me that I need to put the exact same text twice? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to use the original text as source message.
Instead, you should use abstract and normalized keys.

- The key will never change over time contrary to the message, so you don't have to modify all your templates if the key change.
- The key give a context (ex: product.form.title, product.form.description...).
- The developer don't care about the text anymore.

See the symfony best practices: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html#translation-keys